# How do you comment out all non-blank non-commented lines in a file?

Tags: vim

I have a file that I want to add a `#` in front of, avoiding any blank lines. The config in question can be found at: https://github.com/koekeishiya/skhd/blob/master/examples/skhdrc

I want to comment them all out and then go through and uncomment what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitution requiring a leading non-`#` achieves both at once:

```
:%s/^[^#]/#&
```

Comment: @filbranden `:g/./norm! I#` is (i think) the same length and conceptually the closest to what was asked.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: That ignores “non-commented”.

Comment: @Ry- Hah yes it is! I'll post a different one.

Comment: I find this to be slightly better: `:g/^[^#]/s/^/#`, it splits the match (which lines to modify) and the action (insert a `#` at the start), furthermore it doesn't need to repeat a character on the replacement side. But I guess I'm nitpicking...

Comment: @Ry- where in OP do you see not touching non-commented lines as a requirement ? The OP says comment out non-blank lines. Also, I would have thought it somewhat unceremonious to destroy (rather than correct) edits to a CW answer. But I’ll post my own instead.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: “How do you comment out all non-blank **non-commented** lines in a file”

Comment: @filbranden: True, those are some nice properties.

Comment: @Ry- eek, i missed the title.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution:

```
:global/^[^#]/s/^/#
```

And if you don't mind the possibility of duplicate `#`s, use `.` as the `global` pattern instead:

```
:global/./s/^/#
```

I'd even argue that this is the *best*, since then you can find commented out code with by searching for `^#[^#]`, and original comments by searching for `^##`.

In either form, instead of `substitute`-ing, you can "insert" by changing the command following `global` to `:normal! I#`

---

`:global` can be shortened to `:g`, and `:normal!` to `:norm!` (in most cases).

Answer (score 0):

The bellow search matches only non-blank lines that do not start with #.  (Thanks [@Ry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/707111/ry)) for his commenting it helped me to give a conciser answer.

```
/^#\@!.

# .................. literal #
\@! ................ negates preceding  atom
.   ................  any char
```

So the solution becomes:

```
:%s/#@!./# &

& ............... the whole search pattern
```

Tip: once you make a search you can do this:

```
:%s//# &
```

The double slashes mean: use the last search on my substitution.

Comment: In terms of which lines are matched, `\v^(#@!\s?.)+` = `\v^(#@!\s?.)` = `\v^#@!\s?.` = `\v^#@!.` = `^#\@!.`.